# error while loading shared libraries: libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-8.1.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: libraries, elementaryos

I successfully built visit using the build_visit script from this page: https://wci.llnl.gov/simulation/computer-codes/visit/downloads and am trying to run it when I encounter this error. I am running this on elementary os.
My install directory is `/home/slimshady/Downloads/visit/`.

I found the `libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-8.1.so.1` file at `/home/slimshady/Downloads/visit/VTK-8.1.0-build` but do not know how to solve this problem.

The complete output I get while trying to run visit is:

[image: Error message]

I get a blank output for `echo $RPATH`, `echo $RUNPATH` and `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Can someone help? Let me know if you want to know more details about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/slimshady/Downloads/visit/
```

and then try to exec the program

Comment: I tried this. It did not work. I tried exporting `/home/slimshady/Downloads/visit/VTK-8.1.0-build/` too, but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I had messed up. `/home/slimshady/Downloads/visit/third_party/vtk/8.1.0/linux-x86_64_gcc-7.3/lib/` was the directory which the packages were supposed to be looking in.